# Meaning of weak solutions in the class $C^{1,\alpha}$

Tags: derivatives, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

There are quite a few papers who, e.g. for the p-Laplace equation, show that weak solutions under some assumptions are not quite in $C^2$ but at least in $C^{1,\alpha}$ (locally). But I am wondering how this is possible as for this the weak solution, let's call it $u$, would have to be classically differentiable with its gradient $\nabla u$ being locally Hölder continuous. But how can a Sobolev-function be classically differentiable? Or does $C^{1,\alpha}$ in context of weak solutions always mean the weak derivative even though the notion $C^{1,\alpha}$ usually means classically differentiable with the derivative being Hölder continuous?

I hope the question is clear. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided I understand your question correctly, I would say that the point of such regularity results is precisely to prove that the weak solution, say $u \in W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ to the problem $- \Delta_p u = f$ enjoys **more** regularity than required by the mere definition of being a weak solution.

Note that saying that $u \in W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ indeed corresponds to saying that $u$ has a weak derivative say $u' \in L^p(\Omega)$. But this does not prevent $u'$ from actually also belonging to $C^0(\Omega)$, so that $u$ is classically differentiable. Here, the results you mention also prove that $u'$ has Hölder regularity.

Maybe what you are missing is the following type of argument, say in 1D to keep things simple: if $u \in L^2(0,1)$ has a weak derivative belonging to $C^0(0,1)$, then $u \in C^1(0,1)$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment! In your last sentences, do you requiere $u\in L^2(0,1)$ such that Morrey's inequality holds due to $kp = p > n = 1$?

Comment: No I was not really using any embedding. Let $u \in L^2(0,1)$. You can define its weak derivative (in the sense of distributions) without any other assumption. Let us call $v \in \mathcal{D}'(0,1)$ this derivative. If you happen to know (for any reason) that $v \in C^0(0,1)$, then this implies that originally $u \in C^1(0,1)$ and $u'$, the classical derivative of $u$ is equal to $v$.

Comment: This sounds interesting. Do you maybe have any references for this result you are using here? I am not aware of this. Thanks a lot for your help btw!

Comment: Maybe I should have been more precise/careful, what I meant is that in such a case, you can choose a $C^1$ representative of $u$ in $L^2(0,1)$ (so a function $\tilde{u} \in C^1$ which is equal to $u$ almost everywhere). It depends on the exact results you are looking for, but maybe Section 19.2 of https://mathweb.ucsd.edu/~bdriver/231-02-03/Lecture_Notes/weak-derivatives.pdf can help you.

Comment: Thank you once again! So if I have understood you correctly, in $1D$ you follow that if $u\in L^2(0,1)$ and the weak derivative has an continuous representative, then $u$ is a.e. in $C^1$ and you follows this from Proposition 19.26 in the linked lecture notes, is this correct?

I am aware of the sobolev embedding theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_inequality

and there they directly show embeddings into certain $C^{r,\gamma}$ spaces, is this related to your argument?

Comment: Yes, all of this is somehow related.